# Laravel DB connection not refreshing after changing the config

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

This is my database connection which I have specified.

```
'mysql_test' => [
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
          'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
          'database'=> '',
          'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
          'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
          'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
          'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
          'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
          'prefix' => '',
          'prefix_indexes' => true,
          'strict' => true,
          'engine' => null,
      ],
```

Now I am trying to change the `database` value from the code and then connection to the database like this

```
 for( $i = 1; $i <=4 ; $i++)
    {
      $db='test_'.$i;
    DB::connection('mysql_test')->statement('CREATE DATABASE '.$db.';' );

   Config::set('database.connections.mysql_test.database' , $db);
    error_log(config('database.connections.mysql_test.database'));
    DB::reconnect('mysql_test');
    error_log(DB::connection('mysql_test')->getDatabaseName());

  }
```

`config` value is getting changed as on the first `error_log`, I am getting my changed `config` value. But when I connect back again to the same connection with the updated config, I am not getting my database name. Connection is not getting associated to any database.

Comment: Change database values in .env file and then restart your artisan server and then check it will be changed.

Comment: I want to change it from code only and I am not running artisan server. I have made a command to setup test database.

Comment: "when I connect back again" what does that mean, in what context? ... no run time changes are shared between processes

Comment: I am reconnecting to the database connection. Why we can't connect to different db connection on same process? @lagabox

Comment: " Why we can't connect to different db connection on same process?" We can connect to different connection on the same process.

Comment: where is this code running, in what context? from the command line, are you running multiple commands? queue jobs?

Comment: I am running this from command line

Comment: Try with `php artisan config:clear` & `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to `purge` the connection so it disconnects and removes it from the cache on the Database Manager:

```
...

Config::set('database.connections.mysql_test.database', $db);

DB::purge('mysql_test');

dump(DB::connection('mysql_test')->getDatabaseName());
```

Comment: works for me (Laravel v10) - thanks so much! I was dynamically changing the db default db connection in a console command - this really saved me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reconnect the db after the config value is changed

`DB::reconnect("mysql_test");`

Comment: Nope, Same result. Not getting it.

Comment: `DB::connection('mysql_test')->getDoctrineConnection()->close();` this is also not working

Comment: What is the result of this ? error_log(DB::connection('mysql_test')->getDatabaseName());

Comment: It is giving blank output

Answer (score 0):

DB::Purge() fixed it for me. It looks like this was needed after Laravel 8.x upgrade. Before the Laravel tasks did switch database connections when needed. After some update they did no longer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue on Laravel 5.7

In my case `DB::purge('mysql_test')` and `DB::reconnect("mysql_test")` also not worked so i did this:

```
$db_connection_name = 'mysql_test'; // Connection name that i wanted to connect
Config::set('database.default', $db_connection_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::setDefaultConnection($connectionName);
```

solved the issue for me. (v8.48)

didn't need to purge or refresh.

Answer (score -1):

This should be more efficient as it won't have to re-connect to the database.

```
DB::table("products")->get(); //tenant A
DB::statement("use tenant_b");
DB::table("products")->get(); //tenant B
```

Comment: If this is an answer, you should consider an [edit] to make it clearer that this is an answer and not a question. If reviewers consider it to be a separate question, it may get deleted in review.