# How to override the Schema connection details during migrations in Laravel 10.x

Tags: php, laravel

Inside of my `AppServiceProvider` I am attempting to hook onto the `MigrationStarted` event to modify the `username` and `password` to the admin user since the tenant user cannot alter tables.

```
public function boot()
{
    foreach ([MigrationStarted::class, MigrationsStarted::class] as $event)
        \Event::listen($event, $this->onAnyMigrationStarted(...));
}

private function onAnyMigrationStarted(MigrationStarted|MigrationsStarted $event): void
{
    config()->set('database.connections.tenant.username', config('database.connections.gateway.username'));
    config()->set('database.connections.tenant.password', config('database.connections.gateway.password'));
    Schema::setConnection(DB::connection('tenant'));
}
```

However, if I `dd(Schema::getConnection(), config('database.connections.tenant))` inside of the migration, I can see that the `Schema` connection is still using the tenant credentials yet the config is successfully updated.

Is there any way to force the Schema connection change in the `AppServiceProvider` without having to set this in all of the migration files?

Note: I don't want the tenant connection to be the table owner or have access to modify tables, I just want to change the connection to the user role that can.

Comment: use the config helper not the env helper when outside [config folders](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-env).

Comment: Yeah, apoligies, I originally thought the config helper wasn't getting the right values so swapped to `env()` call. I can assert that it is getting the right values and I'll change it back to the `config()` call. Just seems the `Schema::setConnection` isn't persisting @francisco

Comment: and just be careful about the `MigrationStarted` vs `MigrationsStarted` they have different [meanings](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#events).

Comment: Thanks again @francisco I went ahead and changed that in my AppServiceProvider and updated the question - really helpful to catch that!

Comment: So, to clarify: users are creating the migration files and running them from the CLI but the credentials they have in their `.env` file cannot alter table structure? I agree events are probably the best approach. A possible solution if that doesn't work could be overriding the built-in `migrate` command and just specifying the connection in there?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the `MigrationsStarted` event is fired after the migration process has already started, and changing the connection configuration at that point might not work as expected, I think you can use `DB::purge()` to clear the cache of connection, and then set the new configs you want to use to connect.

You can refer to the answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361871/laravel-db-connection-not-refreshing-after-changing-the-config)

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.